# __imp link errors using g++ running under mingw

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, imp

I have a simple socket program that I'm trying to compile using g++ running in mingw (both the latest versions) on a Win8 system.  I'm getting the common linker errors

```
undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
```

I've tried adding -lws2_32 with no luck; i.e. it still can't find the references.  Can someone suggest something else I might be missing?

Here's the full output:

```
G:\source\kak>g++ -o ./test_client -lws2_32 test_client.C
C:\Users\kenkahn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDZTr9b.o:test_client.C:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr'
C:\Users\kenkahn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDZTr9b.o:test_client.C:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
C:\Users\kenkahn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDZTr9b.o:test_client.C:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `__imp_connect'
d:/program files/mingw/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\kenkahn\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDZTr9b.o: bad reloc address 0xc in section `.xdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Post the output of your `g++` command with `-v` added to the options.  Also, keep in mind that "latest versions" isn't very helpful with gcc or MinGW since there are many different sources for these.  For example, it looks like you're using gcc 4.8.1 - I have a MinGW install with gcc 4.8.2.

Answer (score 23):

Try putting the `-lws2_32` after the `test_client.C` parameter. The linker of gcc (ld) is touchy about the order of linkable things, this is probably why it doesn't find your imported functions at link time.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please **accept** it (green tick).

Comment: I wasted half an hour on this, probably would have battled for another hour without your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very interest experience.

I am facing the same issue Within Code::Blocks by default.

Not works by default

```
g++.exe -o bin\Release\ServerClient.exe obj\Release\main.o -s -lws2_32 -lWinmm C:\Projects\_Dep\enet\bin\Release\libenet.a -v > nejde 2>&1
```

It works from command line if I change order of the libs

```
g++.exe -o bin\Release\ServerClient.exe obj\Release\main.o -s C:\Projects\_Dep\enet\bin\Release\libenet.a -lws2_32 -lWinmm -v > jde 2>&1
```

Diff of these is:

```
 C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\tomas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWeJOL1.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o bin\Release\ServerClient.exe -s C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0 -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../.. obj\Release\main.o C:\Projects\_Dep\enet\bin\Release\libenet.a -lws2_32 -lWinmm -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtend.o
```

vs

```
 C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\tomas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLEHscT.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o bin\Release\ServerClient.exe -s C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0 -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../.. obj\Release\main.o -lws2_32 -lWinmm C:\Projects\_Dep\enet\bin\Release\libenet.a -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/crtend.o
```

Detailed diff focus on attached picture.

[image]

Comment: I feel necessary to mention here solution how to avoid this issues in Code::Blocks IDE.

It is pretty simple. 

In Code::Blocks in compiler you can select order for added Link libraries.
You have for choice Prepend/Append those arguments and fix the issue.

It is existing still one more drastic settings in libraries order parameters via Global Compiler settings, but this I don't recommend due possibility of dynamically set for individual projects as required.