# linking errors : undefined reference to `__imp_socket'

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I have a simple client-server program in C, I am trying to compile it using GCC (the latest version) on windows10 but I am getting some linking errors like

> undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_bind'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_listen'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_accept'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
>
> undefined reference to `__imp_connect'

I've tried adding -lws2_32 with no luck; i.e. it still can't find the references. Can anyone else think of anything else I might be missing?

[image: ERROR MESSAGE FOR SERVER]

[image: ERROR MESSAGE FOR CLIENT]

server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
// system file contains definations of system calls
// include<sys/socket.h>
#include <winsock.h>
//#inlude<netinet/in.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Port number not provided. program terminated\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, n;
    char buffer[255];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("Error opening Socket.");
    }
    // memset((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset((char *)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        error("Binding Failed.");
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    // 5 is the number of cilents that can connect at the moment
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
        error("Error while accepting");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, 256);
        n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            error("Error while reading the message");
        }
        printf("Client : %s\n", buffer);
        memset(buffer, 0, 255);
        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

        n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0)
        {
            error("Error while writing");
        }
        int i = strncmp("Bye", buffer, 3);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// read write
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
// system file contains definations of system calls
// include<sys/socket.h>
#include <winsock.h>
//#inlude<netinet/in.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2ipdef.h>
// #include <netdb.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[255];
    if (argc < 3)
    // if less than 3 host has not provided port no.
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        error("Error opening socket");
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error , no such host");
    }
    memset((char *)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *)server->h_addr_list, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        error("Connection failed");
    }

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer, 0, 255);
        fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
        n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0)
        {
            error("Error while writing");
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, 255);
        n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            error("Error while reading");
        }
        printf("Server: %s", buffer);
        int i = strncmp("Bye", buffer, 3);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I've tried adding -lws2_32 with no luck* - show how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_imp link errors using g++ running under mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314120/imp-link-errors-using-g-running-under-mingw)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added images let me know if that helps.

Comment: Your screenshots show that both programs are compiled properly and are being executed. So what is your question then? If they don't *run* as you expect, it is a different question and unrelated to this one.

Comment: I agree, you should **edit** your question to ask about the "Error opening socket". Your program compiles fine, this is definitely **not a linker problem**.